# Is there a single word which means "a person, and all of his ancestors", or "a person, and all of his descendants"?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, collective-nouns, terminology

There are a lot of words describing ancestral relationships between people, such as:

```
parent
grandparent
great-grandparent
any of the above can be described as an "ancestor".

child
grandchild
great-grandchild
any of the above can be described as a "descendant".
```

I am wondering if there are single words (nouns) which describe any of the following concepts:

```
A person and all of his/her ancestors
A person or any of his/her ancestors
A person and all of his/her descendants
A person or any of his/her descendants
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14):

[Lineage](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lineage) comes to mind (as did ***Line*** but I prefer lineage)

> 1. lineal descent from an ancestor; ancestry or extraction: She could trace her lineage to the early Pilgrims.
> 2. the line of descendants of a particular ancestor; family; race.

Since there is some discussion about whether or not the person itself belongs to the lineage, I offer this [ngram](http://goo.gl/Ndy171) of "last of his lineage"

Comment: Correct. Although *lineage* is considered a synonym of *line*, it being derived from *line* (see my answer), is more often used in a renounification sense. *Our lineage* should be more common than *We are the lineage*.

Comment: I considered Line, but prefer lineage

Comment: That's fine, too, but I see a difference as I said.

Comment: @mplungjan: Does "lineage" mean "A person **and** all of his/her ancestors", as per the OP's request? I thought "lineage" was more like a single line of ancestors back to a particular ancestor, but *excluding* the person themselves.

Comment: It is the person's lineage so the person belongs to it too.

Comment: Just because it "is the person's lineage" does not mean the person belongs to it. It's easy to interpret "lineal descent from..." as meaning the lineal descent itself, not inclusive of the terminus (the person) of that lineal descent. In most usage of *lineage* I have always interpreted it to mean the lineal descent *excluding* the person, much like the notion of a head and a tail for a list. If a list is comprised on the first element followed by all of the remaining elements, you can call the first element the head and the rest the tail, so that the head is not really a part of the tail.

Comment: I disagree. But that is just my opinion. The list comprises the head AND tail both. The person is the head and the tail is his ancestors. The list is his lineage of which he is the last unless he has children. http://goo.gl/Ndy171

Answer (score 6):

For all of his descendants, *progeny* (google's def):

> a descendant or the descendants of a person, animal, or plant; offspring.

For all of his anscestors, you can use *forebears*:

> an ancestor

OR forefathers / foremothers

OR primogenitors:

> an ancestor, esp. the earliest ancestor of a people; a progenitor.

Answer (score 2):

For most purposes in general English writing, where readability is more important than terminology, the familiar, well understood word ***line*** should eminently serve the purpose, with its meaning amply clear from the context.

*[line<sup>1</sup>](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/line)*

> **19**
>   a. Ancestry or lineage.
>   b. A series of persons, especially from one family, who succeed each other: *a line of monarchs; comes from a long line of bankers.*

Answer (score 2):

I'd think that you could refer to a person's *dynasty* as including themselves and their ancestors/descendants, but it carries connotations of nobility that might be unwanted.

Answer (score 1):

While perhaps more often used to describe a depiction of the relationships, the term **[family tree](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/family%20tree)** is often used for the relationships themselves

> The ancestors and descendants of a family considered as a group

Answer (score 0):

In legal language you might see, the decedent and his descendants per stirpes, but this relates to line as above.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "ourselves and our posterity" has been used to convey a similar meaning.

Comment: the OP specifically asked for a single-word meaning. :)

Comment: Of course you're right, but I couldn't think of one. I'm sure Gouverneur Morris spent many hours phrasing the preamble to the United States Constitution, and neither he nor any of the other talented men at the Philadelphia Convention could do any better, well, I don't think I there is anything better!

Comment: The framers of the constitution are not responsible for your inability to deliver an answer. Opinion is what "comments" are for, and you have enough rep to make them. Use it. It's considered a privilege.

Comment: Light humor. Some people like it, some people don't. Sorry you feel offended.

Answer (score -4):

Not really. The word that is nearest to what you are seeking is genealogy.

Answer (score -5):

In English the word is "family."