# Single English word for Family Tree?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary, computing

In computer science, when we are doing object oriented programming, we define **parent-child relationship**. If we define the Parent class (Top root) and a number of Children classes (Siblings nodes), we can treat this like a family; but I need a single technical English word which gives the idea of (Father [Me]) -> My Children -> My Grandchildren-> Their Children)—and not *ancestry* (because Ancestors -> Their Children -> My Parents -> Me).

Hope you guys understand my question. Please provide a single English word.

Comment: Lineage works .

Comment: Descendants, progeny, offspring.

Comment: Thank you very much guys.But problem is "Progeny or Lineage" means my children and grand children and their children but without me(Root),I need a word which Includes "me"(origin) also.Simply a word which implies "Me and my Progeny/bloodline/Offspring"

Comment: Is there a reason why **Family** doesn't cover the idea you want? I found the definition: All the descendants of a common ancestor.

Comment: Family kind of non-technical.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because naming programming-based things is off-topic.

Comment: related:[Is there a single word which means “a person, and all of his ancestors”, or “a person, and all of his descendants”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/151741/is-there-a-single-word-which-means-a-person-and-all-of-his-ancestors-or-a-p) and [Adjective describing a person who has lots of children, not “fertile”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/240759/adjective-describing-a-person-who-has-lots-of-children-not-fertile) This question appears to be a duplicate of the last one. But I don't know enough about computer programming to say for sure.

Comment: What about Hierarchy?

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on skull patrol's answer, perhaps "lineage" might work:

> **lineage**
>
> the members of a person's family who are directly related to that person and who lived a long time before him or her

*Source: Cambridge Dictionaries Online*

Answer (score 1):

How about **genealogy**?

Google defines it this way:

**ge·ne·al·o·gy** ˌjēnēˈäləjē,ˌjēnēˈaləjē noun
a line of descent traced continuously from an ancestor.

"combing through the birth records and genealogies"
**synonyms:**   lineage, line, line of descent, family tree, bloodline; More
the study and tracing of lines of descent or development.

a plant's or animal's line of evolutionary development from earlier forms.

Answer (score 1):

To combine and expand on several other answers:

**Genealogy** is the most broad categorization. It includes straight lines from grandparent to you, you to grandchildren, etcetera. But it also includes detours that go up and down generations like up to grandmother and then down to uncle and to cousins.

**Lineage** is everything in a 'direct line'. So it includes your grandparents (up, up), grandchildren (down, down), but not your uncle (up, up, down).

**Ancestors** are those who come before you. Anyone that comes before you (not sure if based on year or generation.) Your uncle is an ancestor.

**Progenitor** is a direct ancestor. A combination of ancestry and lineage. (grand)parents are in here, but your uncle isn't.

**Descendants** are all your offspring. This doesn include those who marry your offspring, but dóes include their children.

**Successors** is the best antonym to ancestors I can come up with. It's all that come after you, but no direct lineage requirement.

**Household**, **Familia** (Latin), **Ménage** (French) or **Gezin**(Dutch) are words that could be used for the conjugal family, i.e. a married couple and their children. But due to death, divorce, children going to live on their own, none of these are particularly precise.

Here's a more visual explanation, with thanks to the Hebblethwaites:
[image]

But what you really mean is a [(sub)tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)#Terminology). It's that simple ;)

Answer (score 0):

> **[Genus](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/genus)** - a class of things that have common characteristics and that can be divided into subordinate kinds